# What's the least intrusive method for creating a backup of a couchdb database?

Tags: backup, couchdb

We're looking to create regular backups of a couchdb database, to ship offsite. What's the least intrusive way to obtain these - ideally without interrupting or significantly slowing down performance on the existing database server?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could just copy the CouchDB database file. Read more about this [here](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/How_to_make_filesystem_backups).

Comment: Above mentioned linked were is not working. returning 404 page not found

Answer (score 5):

Why not use CouchDB replication to replicate the production database to another host where the backups can be performed?

Comment: This will not copy the `_security` object since it is considered to be metadata about that DB URL and not metadata about the contents of the DB. If you need to remember your admin and reader names and roles, you must back that up too.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use couchdb-dump and couchdb-load for Backup and restore to normal text files.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a Linux or MacOSX user you can use the [couchdb-dump tool](https://github.com/animamea/couchdb-dump), which basically works on bash shell.

It dumps the database on a local file (ASCII text file), formatted as requested by http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API

Then you can restore it with the bulk document upload or with the couchdb-dump restore tool.

Backing up the files has the advantage of being very quick, but the disadvantage of working on local files which cannot be used when changing OS.

You can find other tools on github:

https://github.com/stockr-labs/couchdbdump

https://github.com/zebooka/couchdb-dump